# How to upload a series of Excel 2013 files using ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web to create a C# program that can process through a list of Excel files (*..xlsx) and read in data from the files.

To begin, I created a webform with a FileUpload control I use to select a file and a Button control I can click to start the import process.  I also have a GridView control to display the data.

I can upload and display data from a single file, but when I upload a second file, click the button control to display the data, I get an error message. "External table is not in the expected format"

Note that I am running a 32-bit version of Excel 2013 on a 64-bit computer.

Below is my code.

Any suggestions???

JBIT

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class WebForm3_ExcellImport_Aymiee : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = "";
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/ExcelFile/" + fileName);
                TextBox1.Text = fileLocation;
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileLocation);
                if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                {
                    connectionString = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
                    + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\"";
                }
                else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                {
                    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                      fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [ID],[Name],[Designation] from [Sheet1$]";
                    dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dtExcelRecords;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                    TextBox1.Text = "Succeeded";
               }
               catch (Exception exp)
               {
                   throw exp;
               }
               finally
               {
                   dAdapter.Dispose();
                   con.Close();
                   con.Dispose();
               }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a very good library that helps you reading the Excel sheets: [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com). Maybe not the easiest way, but definitely more control and easier deployment (no Office needed on server).

Comment: What's the full error message? What line?

Comment: aspose may be worth a look as well

Comment: check your second excel it is in currect format data?